# Lights look different in Three.js than 3DS Max

Tags: three.js, webgl, lighting, 3dsmax

I am using the r65 of Three.js.  When I light a scene in 3ds max I then export it as a an obj to load in Three.js.  I take a second step and export the model to FBX so I can extract the lighting and load in Three.js.  I am noticing that the lights are not as "strong" in Three.js, almost like a multipier should be added to the intensity possibly?  Could it be that I am missing some property on the light in Three.js?

Here is what the scene looks like in 3ds Max
[image: 3ds max]

Here is what it looks like when it's imported to Three.js
[image: Three.js]

After playing around with settings, after turning on the gammaOutput and gammaInput
[image: gammaOutput on]

So it looks a little better with the gamma output on, but still not what I was hoping it would look like from 3ds max.  I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fTEY/4/) but due to the Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors I couldn't figure out how to get the fiddle to work, but hopefully the code there will help see what I am trying to do.

```
// scene
scene = new THREE.Scene();

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

renderer.gammaOutput = true;
renderer.gammaInput = true;

container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();

var modelFilePath = "http://goo.gl/ecHpSf?gdriveurl";
var materialFilePath = "http://goo.gl/bZWZEA?gdriveurl";

loader.load(modelFilePath, materialFilePath, function (object) {

        materials.push.apply(materials, object.children);

        scene.add(object);      
        object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    });

// setup lighting
var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position = new THREE.Vector3(32.2274, 54.6139, 38.2715);
light.distance = 103.74199676513672;
light.intensity = 1;
scene.add(light);
```

Can anyone suggest anything that might help, it seems like I am close.  Thanks!

Comment: FBX is mainly for export mesh and animation, you can't trust and expect the lighting to be fair reproduced externally. You should rebuild your lighting setup in your scene, or tweak the max values, but if the exporter make changes in new updates it may break your setup.

Comment: Denys, Thanks for your input.  You are completely write, the more and more I think about it, the lighting should be done in the rendering engine as opposed to a third-party modeling app.  Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further experimenting I have found that 3ds max has values set for far attenuation start/end.  As far as I can tell, there is no way to export this value into Three.js since far attenuation [End] == Distance.  Doing a search, it looks like I am limited by the values the light source takes in Three.js.  I will follow this up with another post on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Do check out material specular component. R65 changed a bit specular component 
computation: #4636 (WebGLRenderer: Specular component implementation)
I've got similar problem implementing A3dsViewer 3ds converter to the three.js.
Try to export/save 3ds file and do conversion with the [A3dsViewer](http://www.aptagraphis.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=48&Itemid=62) to the three.js 
maybe such workflow will help.

Additionally maybe such settings can help:

```
renderer.gammaInput = false; // do false
renderer.gammaOutput = true;
```

Comment: Hey slider, thanks for that tip!  I did see the same issue with r64 but updated yesterday so I could be sure to be on the latest.  Will give the A3dsViewer conversion a try and update the post if I'm successful, thanks!

Comment: Hi Slider, updating the post after using A3dsViewer, this actually degraded quality quite a bit.  After exporting from max into a 3ds format and exporting from the tool you suggested, it doesn't look like it takes distance into account.  But also it looked much different in A3dsViewer then it did in max.  However, I am going to see if there might be any other tools out there for exporting.

Comment: Could you send me by email(or a link to download) a *.3ds model I would check the possibilities and would try to fix the export code.